# Перечисление в Java

Tags: java

Проблема в том, что не могу задать конкретное значение элементу в перечислении.

```
enum SimpleEnum {
    Var1 = 1; // не работает
}
```

Возможно ли такое в Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите вот [этот](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) пример.
Если же вам нужно просто по порядку нумеровать, тогда Java сделает это за вас.

```
enum SimpleEnum {
    SMTH1, SMTH2
}

...
//Имя
SimpleEnum.SMTH1.name();
//Порядковый номер
SimpleEnum.SMTH2.ordinal();
//Весь сет
SimpleEnum.values()... //обычный массив
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Почти,

```
enum SimpleEnum {
private int a;
    Var1(1);
private SimpleEnum (int a){
 this.a= a;
}
public int getA(){
return a;
}
}
```

Далее просто в Классе выбрать SimpleEnum.Var1.getA();